# In search of an easier way to get ImmutableMultimap<String, String>'s get to return sorted

Tags: java, guava

I have an ImmutableMultimap and I need to present its values as a sorted list.  The following code works, but seems rather inefficient.  I am in search of a way "up-front" to set up for the get( value ) method call to just always return a sorted list.  I don't see, for example, a class like ImmutableSortedMultimap laying around which would make getting this done obvious.  How can I get this done such that the get( value ) call always returns the ImmutableCollection sorted?

```
private ImmutableMultimap<String, String> FIELDS_TO_TYPES = 
    ProfileTypeManager.getFieldsToTypes();
...
String value = getDataSourceFieldId();
ImmutableCollection<String> types = FIELDS_TO_TYPES.get( value );
display = String.format( "%s %s", display, Ordering.natural().sortedCopy( types ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating the `ImmutableMultimap`, `ImmutableMultimap.Builder` has an `orderValuesBy` method, so you'd do something like

```
ImmutableMultimap.Builder<String, String> builder = ImmutableMultimap.builder()
   .orderValuesBy(comparator);
// put values in builder
```

Comment: That works.  Interestingly enough, my multimap is often .inverse()'ed so i ended up having to both orderValuesBy as well as orderKeysBy.  Thanks.